# How can I get all http hosts out of a webpage connection?

Tags: http, selenium, browser, host

I'm trying to build an automation that can retrieve all connections being made within a single webpage connection, just as I can see in browser debuggers under "sources".
basically I want a script that would open a browser, connect to a webpage, analyse the traffic and return a list of all the domains that my browser is connecting to within this single webpage connection.

I tried working with a combination of selenium and pyshark and analyse a live capture, but I encountered 2 problems:

1. both "driver.get('url')" and "capture.sniff(timeout=t)" are commands that cannot execute in the background, which means I cannot trigger them together and sniff whatever the selenium webdriver is doing
2. When I manually checked this by analyzing a cap file I discovered that the results are not reliable, meaning, there were plenty of domains which I could see in my browser debugger that the capture didn't catch.

I'm sure there's a better way to do that. Maybe a browser's debugger API?

Help!

Thanks,

Yarden

Comment: Do not use a browser (or Selenium) for this. Look into any REST library for whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate `BrowserMobProxy` and `Selenium` and get those domains.

`BrowserMobProxy` main page: https://bmp.lightbody.net/

Part of custom integration snippet (`Java`):

```java
import net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.Har;
import net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.HarEntry;
import net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.ProxyServer;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;

...

public class NetworkTrafficInterceptor extends ProxyServer {

  private static final int MAX = 8080;
  private static final int MIN = 7070;
  private final int portNumber;
  private Har har;

  public NetworkTrafficInterceptor() {
    super();
    portNumber = MIN + (int) (Math.random() * ((MAX - MIN) + 1));
  }

  public Proxy startSeleniumProxyServer() {
    try {
      setPort(portNumber);
      start();
      return seleniumProxy();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new WebDriverException(ex);
    }
  }

  public void startIntercepting(String networkTrafficDumpName) {
    this.har = newHar(networkTrafficDumpName);
  }

  public boolean searchRequestUrlInHar(String needle) {
    har = getHar();
    for (HarEntry entry : har.getLog().getEntries()) {
      if (entry.getRequest().getUrl().contains(needle)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public int getResponseHttpStatusCode(String requestedUrl) {
    for (HarEntry entry : getHar().getLog().getEntries()) {
      if (entry.getRequest().getUrl().contains(requestedUrl)) {
        return entry.getResponse().getStatus();
      }
    }
    throw new WebDriverException(requestedUrl + " request is not sent");
  }

  ...
}
```

I believe `entry.getRequest().getUrl()` method should help you to collect those domains.